# Android APK Compiler

Tags: java, android, компиляция, apk

Есть такая тема, мне нужно сделать программу на андроиде, которая будет компилить другие программы. Например: AIDE в гугл плей. Объясните, как скомпилить апк используя ресурсы и java файлы? Можно не кодом, просто объясните что происходит во время компиляции, я сам перепишу на java.
Заранее спасибо!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё оказалось проще, чем я думал. В андроиде есть встроенный aapt и с помощью shell-скриптов его можно запустить